# Setting "a" color withing a "li" on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm using a platform that allows the user to change the elements settings with css, and I'm trying to make the "a" change color when hovering over the "li", but the color of the "a" does not change, how should i fix this? And I know I can change the "a" if I hover over it, but I want it to change while hovering over the "li".

```
<div class="top">

<ul class="menu">
<li><a>Home</a></li>
<li>Products

<ul class="submenu">
<li><a>T-Shirts</a></li>
<li><a>Shirts</a></li>
<li><a>Tank Tops</a></li>
</ul>

</li>


</ul>

</div>

.submenu li{
background-color:#262626;
color:white;
}

.submenu li:hover{
background-color:white;
color:#262626;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML please.

Comment: The answer I posted will work, but I recommend not doing it this way.  If at all possible, it is better to add `display:block` (or `inline-block`) to the anchor itself and add padding and background color to the anchor instead of the li.  This way, when the user hovers over it and tries to click, he isn't confused by nothing happening if he doesn't happen to click directly on the anchor itself.

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple of ways.

```
.submenu li:hover{
    background-color:white;
}
.submenu li:hover a{
    color:#262626;
}
```

or

```
.submenu li:hover{
    background-color:white;
    color:#262626;
}
.submenu li a{
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joseph Marikle.

Comment: @GabrielFerraz There is no need to comment to thank someone, accepting the answer is enough, you even gain 2 reputation.

Comment: @GabrielFerraz You're welcome.  Glad I could help. :)